# Android: network_security_config to choose cleartext communication only on local LAN

Tags: android, http, security, https

the concept of "network_security_config" entry is clear - but I need to access other devices on the local (!) network using HTTP (that is, wallboxes and PV systems and home batteries), but force secure connections into the internet.

I have found no way to enter the local LAN (entering all IP addresses of potential customer's LANs is not possible of course) into the "network_security_config" XML file.

Answer (score 0):

For local http set android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml
This should not affect https connections.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have, and it works, but the Play Console always reminds me that I should change that, as it's a security risk. So I want to add the "secure externally, insecure local" to minimize this issue.

Comment: You could try to generate all IP addresses, but I think it's overkill. iOS has App Transport Security (ATS) which allows local network http by default, with some limitations (i.e. if a user has a domain name registered on the local network, it will not work). I don't believe there is an Android equivalent.  You could make sure the user is using https for outside connections if you check the host before making a connection and changing to https if not in the range of local IP Addresses as usesCleartextTraffic does  not change https settings.

Comment: This will - unfortunately - not stop google to complain about the security risk from unsecured traffic settings. Yes I know I can keep it unsecured by the manifest, and I don't care about security itself as I communicate with local devices (wallboxes, PV plant, smartmeter) and I know what they are doing (and usually don't support HTTP).

Thank you for your ideas though. Seems that Google did something with good intentions and forgot usages like this.